# Seeking Nigeria administrative boundaries

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, nigeria

I am looking for Nigeria administrative boundaries (0-3) level
especially the 3 rd level which is called  "senatorial districts".

Where can I find these?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) is a good resource for country admin boundaries, both internal and external.

Try these shapefiles: [gadm36_NGA_shp](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/shp/gadm36_NGA_shp.zip)

There are three levels available:

- 0-Country (1)
- 1-State (37)
- 2-Local authority (775)

From your question you're asking for [senatorial districts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senate_of_Nigeria), of which there are 109. Each state is split into 3 districts and the composition appears to be based on local authority bounds (level 2).  You could therefore try using the level 2 local authority bounds with the [district composition](https://nigerianinfopedia.com/official-full-list-109-senatorial-districts-in-nigeria/) to merge into senatorial district bounds.

Comment: thanks for your help. But both GADM resource and gadm36_NGA_shp proved admin boundaries for 2 levels only. I need the 3 rd level

Comment: you appear to need a level which is between 1 and 2.  I have clarified the answer.